# Excel VBA dividing 2 by 60

Tags: vba, excel

Have you ever noticed a problem dividing 2 / 60 in Excel Vba code? I am using Excel 2013. Please test the code below:

```
Sub test1()
Dim A As Integer
Dim B As Integer
MsgBox 2 / 60
A = 2
B = 60
MsgBox A / B
End Sub

Sub test2()
Cells(1, "a") = 2
Cells(1, "b") = 60
Cells(1, "c") = Cells(1, "a") / Cells(1, "b")
MsgBox Cells(1, "a") / Cells(1, "b")
End Sub
```

Test1 will generate a wrong answer for the math operation. Result should be 0,0333333, but it brings 3,3333333E-02. Test2 works with cells and it brings correct result.
What is wrong with my code? Is it a bug? I am soooo intrigued, why can't vba do the right calculation?

Thanks for the help

Comment: 3.33x10^-2 exactly equals 0.0333.  Just slightly different notation.

Answer (score 4):

In number part `E+XX` or `E-XX`, `XX` denotes how many digits the decimal point is shifted right or left.

So in your 3.333333E-02 shift the decimal point 2 places left and you get 0.03333333

One of the points of such a notation is to spare you from zeros (0.0000012345 = 1.2345E-06) and to correctly show you only digits which are within the number precision (hypthetical 1234567890123456789 = 1.2345678E+18 (rest of digits is 'clipped').

And 5E+00 = 5 :) no shift.

More information: [E notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation)

Comment: Hummm ok. But, is there a way to prevent VBA doing that? I need the number 0,03333, not the other one. I tried the FORMAT function with no luck.

Comment: **(1)** If you have number `0,03333` in your cell, in Excel (not in VBA) try changing *cell format* – play with offered cell formats. If none of existing formats works for you, you can try elaborate [custom numeric cell format](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Create-or-delete-a-custom-number-format-78f2a361-936b-4c03-8772-09fab54be7f4). If you finally find which one works for you then you can **(2)** set format property of your cell using VBA whenever you need.